# Best way to associate pre-existing model instances to a new parent model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Let's say I've created a few `BoxModel`s, and every object has one field with a `ForeignKey` to a `DeliveryRouteModel`. At the time of creation, the FK field is empty.

Now, in a `DeliveryRouteModel` form, I want to create a new Delivery Route and, besides of its own fields, I want to add a number of `BoxModel`s that I will load via Ajax into the form (by adding the ID of the newly created `DeliveryRouteModel` to the `BoxModel`) .

What's the proper way to do it? Should I create a BoxFormSet and add it to the form? Or should I pass every Box ID as arguments without any Formset?

P.S: Remember I just want to add the new ID to the `BoxModel` `ForeignKey`

Comment: Do you mean `BoxModel` *models* or *objects*?

Comment: Every object, sorry. I already edited the post.